# Como recuperar remotamente do PHP o texto das mensagens no jquery.validate

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Amigos, gostaria de saber como recuperar remotamente do PHP o texto das mensagens no jquery.validate.

```
$('#ajax_form_inclusao').validate({
    rules : {
        numeroContrato : {
            required : true
        },
        dataInicial : {
            required : true,
            dateTimeBR : true
        },
        dataFinal : {
            required : true
        },
        valorPF : {
            required : true
        },
        qtdPFContratado : {
            required : true
        },
        status : {
            required : true
        }
    },
    messages : {
        numeroContrato : {
            required : errorMessages.E2
        },
        dataInicial : {
            required : 'Preencha o campo Data Inicial'
        },
        dataFinal : {
            required : 'Preencha o campo Data Final'
        },
        valorPF : {
            required : 'Preencha o campo ValorPF'
        },
        qtdPFContratado : {
            required : 'Preencha o campo Quantidade de PF Contratado'
        },
        status : {
            required : 'Selecione uma op&ccedil;&atilde;o para o campo Status'
        }
    },
    submitHandler : function(form) {
```

Eu gostaria apenas de colocar todas as mensagens do sistema num arquivo central único e recuperar o texto das mensagens no scripts.

Comment: Estou com uma dúvida para poder te dar a melhor resposta possível. Qual é o objetivo de receber o texto do *validate* no php? Você quer facilitar o tratamento destes erros no php?

Comment: @ErlonCharles Ele quer ter as mensagens de erro centralizadas pra não ter que reescrever isso no server-side.

Comment: O ideal seria ter centralizadas no *server* e carrega-las no *client*, assim é uma maneira muito melhor de manter, o contrário é bem menos eficiente e complicado de manter.

Answer (score 1):

Você **não** precisa fazer validações server-side. Para simplificar, não há necessidade de ter isso no lado do servidor, porque ele não trabalha com a camada de **apresentação**. Se você assim o fizer, vai entrar em um hiato conceitual.

O mecanismo natural do jQuery Validation, em primeiro lugar, não suporta – nativamente – esse tipo de operação. Em suma, você não vai conseguir passar do cliente para o servidor essa tal mensagem de erro – ainda bem, porque isso não faz qualquer sentido.

O que você poderia fazer é: através do `submitHandler` do jQuery Validation, enviar – com JSON – um número de erro para lá no servidor, buscar em um banco de dados a mensagem correspondente ao número solicitado e então retornar à visão. Se você assim o fizer, vai ter o efeito desejado: um repositório centralizado de mensagens de erro.

Centralizar essas mensagens é bom? Teoricamente **sim**. É necessário? **Não**.

Validação de mão dupla é necessária sim, mas invocar um erro no formato de mensagens na direção do servidor não é conveniente. ***Ah, mas e se o cliente desabilitar o JavaScript?*** É como eu disse, você só não deve *invocar* mensagens, mas continue validando para que a ação requisitada não seja processada.

#### Mas Guilherme, ainda não entendi o porquê não de eu não poder passar a mensagem do cliente para o servidor.

*A mensagem é para o cliente.* Nesse caso específico de validação, ela nasce no cliente e fica ali. O *server-side* **não** tem que lidar com a parte de apresentação –  só e somente só deve ser um catalisador que propaga informações de rotas, mas ele é matemático – não sabe pintar um quadro ou escrever um livro; só lida com números, a parte burocrática. **Como eu disse, isso é assassinato conceitual.**

#### Eu *acho* que entendi. Mas e se mesmo assim eu quiser fazer?

O jQuery Validation não vai dispor uma solução tangível nativamente.

Antigamente, quando eu queria fazer a mesma coisa que você, eu criava um banco de dados para armazenar várias mensagens à respectivos identificadores (*ids*) e quando quisesse resgatá-las [as mensagens de erro], eu fazia uma requisição – assíncrona, com AJAX – para buscar no meu "repositório" e assim que encontrado, indicava que a minha ação repassasse a informação obtida à *view* novamente.

De qualquer forma, o processo acima eu já não acho muito mais válido hoje. O seu que é passar do cliente pra o serivdor é, na *minha* opinião, pior ainda. Portanto, evite.